# ModuleNotFoundError in Visual studio for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, virtualenv

I was trying to follow this video posted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySRQsrkrVCU

I setup a virtual environment following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wuuiga0wKdQ
made the requrement.txt file here

[image]

and installed it here
[image]

now when I try to run my code I get an error saying Modulenotfound no module named 'yfinance'
I am confused as to what the problem is for this, I also had a general question about virtual environment in VS code, every time I start a new project, will I have to go through the video and make new path or is there a terminal code I can run?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `where pip3`?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least 2 different problems:

1. In the third image you are trying to execute a python script with a Python binary that is not in your virtualenv.
2. VS code may not be configured right to use your virtualenv's python interpreter.

Edit: it may only be the 2 if the third image is a screenshot from your VS Code terminal and not an external cmd and assuming you are running your Python code within the editor tools.

If that's the case, check your `launch.json` file in VS code. It should be something like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "<path to your virtualenv>/bin/python",
            "program": "${fileBasename}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure your `"python"` is pointing to the right python binary  a.k.a. the one in your virtualenv path.

Then in VS code's general settings you can set `"venvFolders"` as a list of paths where your virtual environments were defined.

```json
{
 ...
 "python.venvFolders:" ["<venv path 1>", "<venv path 2>"]
}
```

Check out [the official guide:](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) and another one related to the [general settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-settings).

Comment: hey so I checked and saw that under my .vscode folder there was no launch.json file, i tried opening it through the command pallete as well but no luck so I just made a new file under .vscode called it launh.json and now tis asking me to make configurations, I just copied your text and added the python folder directing it to the virtual env and now I am getting error saying The python path in your debug config is invalid

Comment: Perfect, now open the python file you are trying to execute and use the VS Code tools to run it. The .vscode has to be placed in the same directory as your file. The config file should try to execute the currently open script file using the python version that you've specified. Also, check out the [settings docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference) as well as the [getting started guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for that extension.

Comment: hey thanks for responding fast, so the code ran once i put them in the same folder but unfortunately I am still getting same eror saying No module found named 'yfinance', I am in the work env where I get that (work_env) sign and PS C:\work\demo> when i hit show in the terminal of vscode it shows that it is installed, but am still getting the same error

Comment: I've updated the answer with the config needed to set `python.venvFolders` on VS Code

Comment: hey so i did that an unfortunately am still the same error, is it possible for me to pm you?

Comment: actually nvm it works

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue may be because your application doesn't use the right Python interpreter or you haven't setup the PYTHONPATH for this application yet.

Trying saving this script as .bat file then put it under your source code then execute this .bat file. Then trying executing your application again.

```
@echo off
echo ---------SETUP PYTHON PATH---------
echo %cd%
setx PYTHONPATH %cd%
echo -----------------------------------------
pause
```